# How to create a multi-series (line) chart with scala-chart

Tags: scala, charts, jfreechart

I came across [Scala-chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart), a really nice wrapper for using [jFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) in Scala. It has several utility classes for generating charts with minimal effort.

What is the best way to generate a line chart with multiple series using scala-chart?

Comment: There is in fact support for both single-series line charts and multi-series line charts (see my answer) -- the chart factories do not even differentiate between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `scala-chart` there are several different ways to create a multi-series line chart. Which way to use depends on how you create your dataset (including ways to work with legacy JFreeChart code):

- (for comparison) create a single-series line chart:

  ```
  val series = for (x <- 1 to 5) yield (x,x*x)
  val chart = XYLineChart(series)
  ```
- build up a multi-series line chart entirely from scala collections (this way I recommend because it is the most idiomatic):

  ```
  val names: List[String] = "Series A" :: "Series B" :: Nil

  val data = for {
    name <- names
    series = for (x <- 1 to 5) yield (x,util.Random.nextInt(5))
  } yield name -> series

  val chart = XYLineChart(data)
  ```
- from a collection of `XYSeries` objects:

  ```
  val names: List[String] = "Series A" :: "Series B" :: Nil

  def randomSeries(name: String): XYSeries =
    List.tabulate(5)(x => (x,util.Random.nextInt(5))).toXYSeries(name)

  val data = for (name <- names) yield randomSeries(name)

  val chart = XYLineChart(data)
  ```
- explicitly create an `XYSeriesCollection` object:

  ```
  def data: XYSeriesCollection = ???
  val chart = XYLineChart(data)
  ```

These are some simple snippets but they should illustrate how data creation is possible and most of the time it boils down to one of these ways.

---

The current implementation (as of 0.4.0) work in the way that:

- all chart factories accept an arbitrary `data` object of type `A` and
- in addition accept an implicit -- a type class like `ToXYDataset[A]` -- which converts this arbitrary `data` of type `A` to the respective dataset the factory is based on
- in the case of xy charts there are default converters for `XYSeries`, `XYSeriesCollection`, `Coll[XYSeries]` (where coll is a scala standard library collection), `Coll[(A,B)]` and `Coll[(A,Coll[(B,C)])]`

This way the chart factories are fully extendable and can be used with `data` instances of your custom types -- you just have to write your own conversion type class instances for your custom types.